# EventBus, recibo datos pero cuando recargo el componente en Vue

Tags: vue.js

tengo dos componentes

Vacante.vue

```
    <template>

      <div v-if="vista == 2">
      <!-- ETIQUETAS DE LA POSTULACION -->

      <form-postulacion></form-postulacion>

    </div>

    </template>


 <script>
        import FormPostulacion from './Postulacion.vue'

     export default{
       components: {
         FormPostulacion,
       },
       data () {
        return {
         vista = 1
        }
       },
        methods:{
          abrirPostulacion(datos){
           me.vista = 2;
           let me = this;
           bus.$emit('AbrirPostulacion', datos);
          },
         }
</script>
```

Postulacion.vue

```
<template>
    Aquí va el formulario de postulación
</template>

<script>
    import bus from '@/event-bus'

export default {

    data () {
        return {
            vacante:{
                fecha_creado: '',
                cargo: '',
                empresa: ''  
            },
        }
    },

    created(){
        bus.$on('AbrirPostulacion', datos => {
            console.log(datos)
        })
    },
    methods:{

    },
}
</script>
```

lo que pasa es lo siguiente, existe una lista de vacantes y cada vacante tiene un botón llamado `Postular` al presionar este botón se ejecuta el método `abrirPostulacion` que se encuentra en el componente Vacante.vue
donde obtengo todos los datos de la vacante seleccionada.

hasta aquí todo bien, de hecho cuando presiono dicho botón me carga la vista correspondiente al formulario de postulación que se encuentra en el archivo Postulacion.vue, en `created()` estoy escuchando el evento emitido en metodo `abrirPostulacion` donde estoy utilizando EventBus, al aplicar un `console.log(datos)` en el archivo `Postulacion.vue` al momento de presionar el boton `Postulacion` no me muestra nada en la consola, sin embargo cuando presiono otro elemento del menú y vuelvo a entrar a la postulación la consola si me imprime los datos de la vacante seleccionada, esto me esta afectando ya que no puedo mostrarle al usuario datos básicos de la postulación como por ejemplo el cargo, fecha de creación, etc.

Espero haber sido claro, agradezco su tiempo... gracias.

Comment: Si esa respuesta no te sirve, por favor avisame asi revisamos que te falto poner y donde.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi, si bien las preguntas tienen muchas similitudes, no soluciona mi problema ya que todo lo que se define en la respuesta lo tengo en mi codigo y aun no logro que funcione.

Comment: Perfecto. Re abro la pregunta, pero por favor agrega un [mcve] donde se refleje el problema. Probablemente pienses que esta todo, pero te falta algo.